# Get the absolute path from std::filesystem::path c++

Tags: c++, c++17, filepath, std, std-filesystem

I have this piece of code

```
auto path = std::filesystem::path("/root/home/../opt/.");
```

I had tried   `std::filesystem::absolute()` but then realized it is for something else than the reasult I want

My question is how can i convert that relative path to the absolute path so that the reasult will be `"/root/opt/"`.

I am using c++17 on Debian g++-9

Comment: You want the canonical path ([link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/canonical)).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `std::filesystem::canonical` to turn the path into an absolute path with all `..` removed ([reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/canonical)):

```
auto path = std::filesystem::canonical("/root/home/../opt/.");
```

Gives you:

```
"/root/opt"
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also use from this function.

```
 std::cout << std::filesystem::path("/root/home/../opt/.").lexically_normal()    << std::endl;
```

Comment: It's worth noting: unlike the other answer (`canonical`), the `lexically_normal` method will not attempt to resolve symlinks, and in fact won't do any file system operations at all. It's just a string manipulation method, hence the name. Depending on the situation, this may or may not be what you want.